# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.objectweb.asm.ClassWriter

Tags: hibernate, java-ee-6

Hi I am developping a small application using hibernate2 and I bumped into the exception that reads java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.objectweb.asm.ClassWriter

Here is the stacktrace:

```
INFO: connection properties: {user=root, password=manel}
16 mai 2011 16:03:27 net.sf.hibernate.transaction.TransactionFactoryFactory buildTransactionFactory
INFO: Transaction strategy: net.sf.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory
16 mai 2011 16:03:27 net.sf.hibernate.transaction.TransactionManagerLookupFactory getTransactionManagerLookup
INFO: No TransactionManagerLookup configured (in JTA environment, use of process level read-write cache is not recommended)
16 mai 2011 16:03:28 net.sf.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: Use scrollable result sets: true
16 mai 2011 16:03:28 net.sf.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: Use JDBC3 getGeneratedKeys(): true
16 mai 2011 16:03:28 net.sf.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: Optimize cache for minimal puts: false
16 mai 2011 16:03:28 net.sf.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: Query language substitutions: {}
16 mai 2011 16:03:28 net.sf.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: cache provider: net.sf.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider
16 mai 2011 16:03:28 net.sf.hibernate.cfg.Configuration configureCaches
INFO: instantiating and configuring caches
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.objectweb.asm.ClassWriter.<init>(Z)V
at net.sf.cglib.core.DebuggingClassWriter.<init>(DebuggingClassWriter.java:47)
at net.sf.cglib.core.DefaultGeneratorStrategy.getClassWriter(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:30)
at net.sf.cglib.core.DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:24)
at net.sf.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:215)
at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory$Generator.create(KeyFactory.java:145)
at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:117)
at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:108)
at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:104)
at net.sf.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.<clinit>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:236)
at net.sf.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:791)
at hibernate.dao.SessionHibernate.rebuildSessionFactory(SessionHibernate.java:68)
at hibernate.dao.SessionHibernate.getSession(SessionHibernate.java:51)
at hibernate.dao.TimesheetDAO.addTimesheet(TimesheetDAO.java:74)
at TestHibernate.main(TestHibernate.java:14)
```

any help please

Answer (score 3):

You need the correct version of [asm](http://asm.ow2.org/) jar on your classpath

Answer (score 0):

you have some conflict with your lib. hibernate uses **cglib-xxxx.jar** and it uses **asm-xxxx.jar**. and there is possibility of having multiple version of these jar either in your project or the other libs you are using may also have some dependency on some other version, so it gets conflict with each other. 
You need to remove your **cglib-xxxx.jar** and replace with **cglib-nodep-xxxx.jar** and use latest **asm-xxxx.jar** or just try by removing **asm-xxxx.jar** from your hibernate dependency, as **cglib-nodep-xxx.jar** will look for another latest **asm-xxxx.jar** in your project or webserver libs. You can find *cglib-nodep* lib from the link
**http://sourceforge.net/projects/cglib/files/**